# Is this the best way to normalise data?

Tags: python-3.x, normalization

I'm wondering if the method below is the best/most efficient way to normalise data in Python. I've seen other methods using scipy but this way seems to work well too. Really just wondering if there's a reason you'd use another method.

```
purch_norm = (dataload.purchase - dataload.purchase.mean()) / (dataload.purchase.max() - dataload.purchase.min())
```

Comment: @philipxy Ahh, thank you for highlighting that there are different methods depending on what you're doing. Wasn't sure if that was the case. I'm normalising ad campaign data so I can plot a scatter and see the overlap in different metrics. The example I'm using I found on stack, it had lots of upvotes so I took it to be correct.

Comment: What is "correct" "normalization" entirely depends on details of what you are doing. But there is *nothing* in your question by which we could answer except the *word* "normalize". I guess you found something like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range). Read that [statistics normalization tag info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/normalization/info), see how wiki 'normalization' has many meanings, read the stats & data links, & google.